# Why is Google Chrome pinging "mdioussrvd" and other random hosts that don't resolve?

Tags: http, google-chrome, chromium

I notice when I start up Google Chrome it makes a few bad requests to random host names, such as mdioussrvd, azwvtdbpjh, and lblhkhlklj.

[image: Picture.png]

I'm wondering what is causing this and/or what the purpose is. At first I thought I had a malicious extension, but I deleted my `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome` folder, deleted Google Chrome, restarted the system, then re-downloaded a clean copy of the latest beta, followed by starting the application using `open -n -a 'Google Chrome.app' --args --disable-extensions`, only to find the same behavior with a fresh install.

The host names are random string each time the program starts. I don't have anything in my hosts file so they are showing erros, as they are not mapped to any particular IP.

I also tried running a file search with grep in both the `Google Chrome.app` folder as well as the `Application Support/Google` folder.

It doesn't matter what the homepage is set to when I start the application. It can be set as the recent tabs page or a web address somewhere. I have to be honest, this is bugging me a little. Does anyone have any thoughts on what tools to use to figure this out?

If you want to see if your install of Google Chrome is doing this, try [Charles Web Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/). It's what I'm using - a great debugging tool and, 8mb in size.

**update**

Same thing happens on Windows XP with the latest (non beta) version of Google Chrome. The homepage is set to the tabs page, no extensions are installed, and all I do is start the browser. The results:

[image: Picture.png]

And here is Chromium on Mac OS X 10.6.7 with no homepage:

[image: Picture 1.png]

Can somebody who develops with the Chromium Projects explain this please?

**note**

I also see a vote to close this - why? I'm trying to trace / debug this and I believe it is relavant to software development and programming. Furthermore if I'm correct this affects a large number of people and warrants an answer.

Comment: Just to confirm this doesn't happen to me - I think you were right in thinking this was something malicious.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have another system to try it on.

Comment: I believe it is malware hijacking browsers. Otherwise maybe google chrome visits those urls to see if it's connected to the Internet or not

Comment: it's odd because there are no extensions installed on it, and those domains don't resolve. furthermore m.edmondson says his does not do this. :(

Comment: @cwd - Do other browsers also do this?

Comment: After more research, no, other browsers are not doing it. Fresh installs of Chrome Beta and Chromium (open source bleeding edge version) both do this, and actually both on Windows and Mac. I'm beginning to think it is a Google Chrome thing. What version are you using and what OS?

Comment: Is it always the same URLs or is it random ones?

Comment: Random as far as I can tell. Charles has a free trial if you want to try and is only 8mb in size - http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: Wrong site. This needs to get migrated to one that caters to these questions.

Comment: A variety of ISPs have systems setup to capture and redirect typo'd domains (e.g. `exmaple.com` instead of `example.com`), so Chrome checks three random URLs on startup to determine what your ISP does with nonexistent domains. See http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55913 for details.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks @Mike West

Comment: @Mike West has posted more about this: https://mikewest.org/2012/02/chrome-connects-to-three-random-domains-at-startup